# Baking metaball solver

Tags: meta-objects

I'm animating a particle system of metaballs, and finding that the scene takes a long time to initialize before it can even start rendering. I'm finding it annoying as I work on materials, since there's a lot of recalculating the same metalballs.

Is it possible to bake complicated metaball calculations?

Comment: In object data tab try to change the render resolution to higher value.

Comment: I've lowered it way down on purpose though. When it's high, I lose too much geometry to the point where the object is unrecognisable.

Comment: Turns out rendering in the viewport does the trick (not sure why hitting F-12 forces a bunch of refreshing though..)

Comment: Rendering in the viewport is fine for playing with material at a single frame. My material is animated, so I really need to step through the timeline to get a feel for how it looks.